# mrjob combiner not working python

Tags: python, mapreduce, mrjob

Simple map combine reduce program: Map column-1 with value column-3 and append `'+'` in each mapper output of same key and append `'-'` after reduce output of same key.
 `input_1` and `input_2` both files contain

```
a 1 2 3
a 4 5 6
```

Code is

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import re
import sys

class MRWordFreqCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        line=re.sub("\s\s+"," ",line)
        s1=line.split()
        yield(s1[0],s1[2])

    def combiner(self, accid, eventid):
        s="+"
        yield (accid, s.join(eventid))

    def reducer(self, accid, eventid):
         s="-"
         yield (accid, s.join(eventid))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFreqCount.run()
```

After executing , `python C:\Python27\map1.py  C:\Python27\input_1.txt C:\Python27\input_2.txt` result is 
`"a" "2-2-5-5"`. Why combiner not works and append '+'.Expected output was:`"a" "2+5-2+5"`. Thanks