# mrjob join non unique key

Tags: python, join, mapreduce, mrjob

Using `mrjob`, I want to map a key of table_1: `a` to values of `x` and `y` from table_2 and table_3, i.e `z` and `w`as shown in output. I write some code [mrjob combiner not working python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118174/mrjob-combiner-not-working-python) which gives output as

```
a1 x1-x2-y1
a2 y1
```

But how to inner join the table_1 table_2 table_3 to get the given desired output. I refer https://gist.github.com/ewencp/7010531 for innerjoin but this may not help in this case.

```
Table_1:
a1 x1
a1 x2
a1 y1
a2 y1

Table_2:
y1 z1
y2 z2

Table_3:
x1 w1
x2 w2

desired output:
a1 w1-w2-z1
a2 z1
```